# Show toll fee for travel itinerary

Tags: web-apps, windows-7, maps

I am looking for a program or a web service that can take as input 2 locations in the US and return the fastest itinerary by car along with the total [toll fee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_toll_roads_in_the_United_States). If possible, free and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate + Google Chrome.

Google Maps only show the presence of toll but don't indicates how much fee there is:

[image]